# Is it possible to show loading bar the the HTML element with only Material UI and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

I'm looking to show a loading bar for when I upload an image with an `input` tag.  I'm using React and Material UI.

I see solutions which use the underlying API which handles the input file by passing the `loading` state to the progress indicator.  But I'm wondering if such a thing exists on the `input` tag itself.

I'm having a hard time looking for something like `onChange` for `input`.  The `onChange` will only execute when the upload is already complete.  I didn't find anything in events which might help: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

```js
  const [fileUploading, setFileUploading] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const handleUploadChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | null) => {
    console.log(event?.target.files)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" component="label">
        Upload file
        <input
          type="file"
          hidden
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={(event) => handleUploadChange(event)}
        />
      </Button>

      {fileUploading && <CircularProgress color="primary" />}
    </>
  )
```

I've tried something like this but has no affect on rendering the progress indicator.

```js
onChange={(event) => {
            setFileUploading(true)
            handleUploadChange(event)
            setFileUploading(false)
          }}
```

Comment: the input is dumb, it has no progress to speak of in that it doesn't load a file, it provides a file interface, and how you use that interface to handle the file data depends on application, therefore it's up to the other parts of the system to determine what "progress" means. As far as the input is concerned, it instantly toggles between 'empty'
 and 'file(s) have been selected'.

Comment: your handleUploadChange does nothing. If it uploads file, then you should async await function and `setFileUploading(false)` after uploaded

Comment: Also, if you want to show the progress, you can use onUploadProgress callback of axios

Comment: So I suppose "...wondering if such a thing exists on the input tag itself" is no it does not exist.  Thank you for the comments, this just means I have to use some other way like Axios.